# Regex for an exception within an exception

Tags: regex, exception

This question here helped me how to do an exception: [Regex with exception of particular words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826059/regex-with-exception-of-particular-words)

Basically, `rx = /^(?!apple$|orange$|banana$)/` would match everything but apple, orange and banana. But now I need to know how to do an exception for an exception.

```
rx = /^(?!.*$)/
```

I believe this would ignore everything, but what should I add to make it match nothing BUT some pre-defined words, like banana and apple?

Comment: er... are you just trying to match banana and apple? /^(apple|banana)$/

Comment: Isn't an exception to an exception just a normal regex? So, to match apple and/or banana (but nothing else), would something simple like `/apple|banana/`work?

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of the opposite of `x` is simply `x`:

```
/^(apple|orange|banana)$/
```

The above regex only accepts input which *exactly* matches `apple`, `orange`, or `banana`.