# Javascript Regexp to match a string which isn't

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this regexp:

```
@([a-z0-9_-]{3,})
```

I don't want it to match if the pattern is "SpecialUsername".

```
@Tom = match
@SpecialUsername = no match
@Another = match
etc
```

How do I modify it for this special case?

Comment: If your blacklist is only the one name, I wouldn't modify the regex. Just do a separate check, if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript regular expression to not match a word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449131/javascript-regular-expression-to-not-match-a-word)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex with exception of particular words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826059/regex-with-exception-of-particular-words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?!SpecialUsername)([a-z0-9_-]{3,})
```

Comment: so it should probably be something like `@(?!SpecialUsername)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,})` ?