# regex findText with exception

Tags: regex-negation

I have a jenkins pipeline in which I've always been searching for a string in case I need to update my build to failure.

```
            findText regexp: 'ERROR', alsoCheckConsoleOutput: true, unstableIfFound: true
```

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/text-finder/

I now need for example to make an exception to allow certain cases of ERROR to be handled differently.

I was looking at this question [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) and this question [Regex with exception of particular words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826059/regex-with-exception-of-particular-words) but I still could not make it work.

I really suck at regex and trying to play with the different websites I'm struggling a bit with the negatives lookup parts.

Basically I want to ensure that

```
This is an ERROR bla bla bla
```

Is an error caught by my regex

But I need to have this as not an error because XYZ shows up before

```
This XYZ is not an ERROR bla bla bla because of the prefix
```

I was trying something like this but not really close.
(ERROR)+?:(XYZ)
Basically ERROR can appear more than once in my output lines but XYZ should never be found. If it helps XYZ will always show up before the ERROR

Any idea?

Comment: If there should be ERROR in the string, and not XYZ then this might work if the lookarounds are supported `^(?!.*\bXYZ\b).*\bERROR\b`

Comment: doesn't seem to work but not sure why. it still matches in both my examples

Comment: Maybe there is a way to match the error and xyz and then negate the result `^.*XYZ.*ERROR|^.*ERROR.*XYZ`

Comment: If it is in Java, try `^(?!.*\\bXYZ\\b).*\\bERROR\\b` or just `^(?!.*XYZ).*ERROR`

Comment: first of all thanks for trying to help, I'm trying just here https://regex101.com/ and neither seem to work

Comment: nevermind it does indeed work I was using a querty keyboard and my swissgerman quertz was playing tricks with me. the ^(?!.*XYZ).*ERROR works